# QImage - работа с изображениями в Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qimage

Доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке "открыть" изображение в Qt Creator.

Собственно код програмы:

```
#include <QtGui/QImage>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str = "file1.bmp";
    QImage* img = new QImage(str.c_str());
}
```

И ругания компилятора:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6QImageC1ERK7QStringPKc'
```

Было бы здорово, если бы кто-то объяснил мне, где я нагрешил и что делаю не так ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убедитесь, что в pro файле добавлен GUI модуль:

```
QT += core gui
```

Это минимальные требования, для того, чтобы Ваша программа собралась.

Comment: Это было настолько просто, что даже обидно.
Спасибо ;)